# Can a that-clause be used a clause of purpose like so that

Tags: grammar

The following quote is from "Mansfield Part" by Jane Austen:

After some minutes spent in this way, , Miss Bertram, observing the iron gate , expressed a wish of passing through it into the park, **that their views and their plans might be more comprehensive**.

Can we construe the that-clause in bold as a so-that clause?  If not, how can we understand it correctly.  Generally speaking, is it possible to omit "so" of the so-that clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction is in place of so that, yes. You can do this in your own writing but it very often is perceived as more formal than the alternative.